# Java regular expression does not match the input

Tags: java, regex

i have a problem with regex. I want to parse url with param which can contains one of the following:

- firstName:*ar*,lastName:smith,
- firstName:*ar*,lastName:smith,addedAt<2020-03-15,
- firstName:*ar*,lastName:smith,phone:123456789,
- firstName:*ar*,lastName:smith,email:email@email.com,

every key-value must ends with comma(,)

I have a regex like that:

- `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\p{Punct}?)((\\w+?)|((\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?+))(\\p{Punct}?),");`
- `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\p{Punct}?)[a-zA-Z](\\p{Punct}?),");`

but it doesn't work with this above inputs except in the first case.

Please about some advices how to properly construct Pattern.

Comment: "every key-value must ends with comma" suggests CSV format, which suggests using CSV parser. Do you *have to* use regex?

Comment: @Pshemo i build the rest controller method something like this: findAllBySearch(@RequestParam("search") String search), so i think it good approach is regex

Comment: @AdrianN. I normally go to online regex evaluators to test them out. My favorite is this https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html, mainly because it has more things I could test and the interface is very clean and easy to use.

Comment: It seems you may use a mere `"(\\w+)\\p{Punct}([^,]*)"` to match and capture the keys and values ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/stCxDN/1)).

Answer (score 2):

What you have is Comma delimited, colon separated key-value pairs. Unless some requirement forces you to use regex, which based on your comment it doesn't, split the value on the comma, then split the resulting array's values on the colon. What you'll end up with is an array of arrays with index 0 being the key, and index 1 being the value.

In the following example, using one of the values provided in OP, we split on the comma and loop through the resulting array splitting each index on the colon and adding it to a list each iteration.

```
String value= "firstName:ar,lastName:smith,email:email@email.com,"
Map<String,String> keyValuePairs = new HashMap<>();
for (String kvp : value.split(",")) {
  String[] kvp = kvp.split(":");
  if (kvp.length != 2 || kvp[0].isEmpty()) {
    continue; //ignoring incorrectly formatted kvp
  }
  keyValuePairs.add(kvp[0], kvp[1]);
}
// do what you want with keyValuePairs;
```

Comment: Agree this is a simpler way to solve the problem. Of course `split()` uses a regex as its argument, so you're still using them!

Comment: That's a decision by the Java core library I'll never understand. But also: simple regex, simple life.

Comment: @RichardBarker thank you for this solution. i think for my purposes is good :)